# Adding HttpClient jar to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, apache-httpclient-4.x

I added the Apache HttpClient 4.3.5 jar to a new user library in my project, but whenever I run my program I receive NoClassDefFound runtime error. I can tell this is caused specifically by the HttpClient classes. I don't know how to alleviate this issue.

Comment: You added the jar through `Add external jars` ?

Comment: How are you running your program exactly? By right clicking a class with a `main()` method from within Eclipse and choosing `Run`? Or on the command line?

Comment: if you using Eclipse,Right click on project,Build path->Add external jars,Select you httpclient jar and press ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NoClassDefFound usually means you're missing required dependencies on the class classpath.

If you take a look at the [Maven pom.xml for httpclient](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.5/httpclient-4.3.5.pom), you will see it has some transitive dependencies, meanings it depends on other artifacts.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So you can see three artifacts `httpclient` is dependent on: `httpcore`, `commons-logging`, and `commons-codec`.

That being said, you may being missing these dependencies (hence the NoClassDefFound). If you are using Maven, when you add `httpclient` as a dependency, Maven will pull these transitive dependencies int for you.

However, it doesn't look like you are using Maven. So what you'll want to do is download the entire package at the [**HttpComponents Home Page**](https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi). If you grab the binary distrubutions, like [**4.3.5.zip**](http://apache.arvixe.com//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.3.5-bin.zip), and unzip it, you will will see all these jars in the `lib` dir:

```
commons-codec-1.6
commons-logging-1.1.3
fluent-hc-4.3.5
httpclient-4.3.5
httpclient-cache-4.3.5
httpcore-4.3.2
httpmime-4.3.5
```

Best thing to do is just add all those jars into one library. Then add all that library to your project.

1. Simple go to [Window] → [Preferences] → [Java] → [Build Path] → [User Libraries]
2. Select <kbd>New</kbd> and type in a name
3. Select the new Library, Select <kbd>Add External Jars</kbd>, browse and add all the jars in the `lib` dir that you downloaded.
4. Add the library to your project.